# Poor camera2 video recording performance

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm attempting to record video via a mediarecorder and the camera2 API and I'm having some difficulty getting good quality recordings out of it.

I am also getting a few different errors in my logcat like "App passed a NULL surface" when starting up the textureview.

Other than that it seems to work, but the captured videos are zoomed in and have a very low framerate ~2 fps.

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
public class VideoTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread thread;

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private String mVideoPath;

    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

    private static final String TAG = "VideoTest";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_test);

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(buttonReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION_PRESSED"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver buttonReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got Button Press!");
            try {
                if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                    i2cRequest(IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_OFF);
                    stopRecordingVideo();

                } else {
                    i2cRequest(IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_ON);
                    startRecordingVideo();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR BLAH CAMERA SUX");
            }
        }
    };

    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Opening Camera");
        try {
            String camId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics cameraChars = camManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraChars.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[14];
            camManager.openCamera(camId, cameraStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable, width="+width+",height="+height);
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
        }
    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onOpened");
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError code: " + error);
        }
    };


    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Starting Preview. ABORTED!");
            return;
        }

        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if(null == texture) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create texture. ABORTED!");
            return;
        }

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        try {
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                    i2cRequest(I2CRequestReceiver.VIDEO_READY);
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onConfigureFailed");
                    i2cRequest(I2CRequestReceiver.E_CAMERA_ERROR);
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void updatePreview() {
        if(null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera Device is Null! ABORT!");
            return;
        }

/*        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);*/
        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, new Range<>(30000,30000));
        thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

        try {
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        thread.quitSafely();
        try {
            thread.join();
            thread = null;
            backgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closePreviewSession() {
        if (null != mPreviewSession) {
            mPreviewSession.close();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera(){
        closePreviewSession();

        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
           mCameraDevice.close();
           mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }


    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
/*
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
*/

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
        profile.audioBitRate = 128000;
        profile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
        profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
        profile.videoBitRate = 2048000;
        profile.videoFrameRate = 30;
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);


/*        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2048000);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);*/
        if (mVideoPath == null || mVideoPath.isEmpty()) {
            mVideoPath = getVideoFilePath();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoPath);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    private String getVideoFilePath() {
        return "/sdcard/LIVE/video/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
    }


    Surface recorderSurface;
    private void startRecordingVideo() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot bind camera, textureView, or previewSize");
            return;
        }
        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            setupMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture!= null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(1280, 720);
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);

            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i2cRequest(I2CRequestReceiver.VIDEO_RECORDING);
                            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Capture failed!");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i2cRequest(I2CRequestReceiver.E_CAMERA_ERROR);
                            mIsRecordingVideo = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },backgroundHandler);

        } catch (IOException | CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {

        try {
            mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        Log.d(TAG, "Video saved: " + mVideoPath);
    }

    private void i2cRequest(String request) {

        Intent sendI2cRequest = new Intent();
        sendI2cRequest.setAction(I2CRequestReceiver.NOWSPEAK_REQUEST_ACTION);
        switch (request) {
            case I2CRequestReceiver.VIDEO_READY:
                sendI2cRequest.putExtra(I2CRequestReceiver.EXTRA_SPEAK, I2CRequestReceiver.VIDEO_READY);
                Log.d(TAG, "VIDEO READY!!");
                break;
            case I2CRequestReceiver.E_CAMERA_ERROR:
                sendI2cRequest.putExtra(I2CRequestReceiver.EXTRA_SPEAK, I2CRequestReceiver.E_CAMERA_ERROR);
                Log.d(TAG, "VIDEO ERROR!!");
                break;
            case IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_ON:
                sendI2cRequest.setAction(IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_CONTROL_ACTION);
                sendI2cRequest.putExtra(IndicatorControlReceiver.EXTRA_INDICATOR, IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_ON);
                break;
            case IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_OFF:
                sendI2cRequest.setAction(IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_CONTROL_ACTION);
                sendI2cRequest.putExtra(IndicatorControlReceiver.EXTRA_INDICATOR, IndicatorControlReceiver.INDICATOR_OFF);
                break;
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendI2cRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE takes frame rates in units of FPS, not 1/1000 of FPS.

So try

```
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, new Range<>(30,30));
```

or even better, pick from the list provided by CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES

Comment: On my platform they seem to be in units of 1/1000 of FPS, and your suggested fix resulted in a warning "W/LegacyRequestMapper: Unsupported FPS range set [30,30]".

`D/VideoTestCam2-FPS-Rang:: LOWER:15000 UPPER:15000 D/VideoTestCam2-FPS-Rang:: LOWER:24000 UPPER:24000
D/VideoTestCam2-FPS-Rang:: LOWER:7500 UPPER:30000
D/VideoTestCam2-FPS-Rang:: LOWER:30000 UPPER:30000`

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @RobGries: Eddy Tavala has forgotten more about Camera2 than I'll ever know. What platform is this that is so far out of spec?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using the Intrinsyc OpenQ 410 platform - 
https://www.intrinsyc.com/snapdragon-embedded-development-kits/snapdragon-410-development-kit/

Comment: @RobGries: You may wish to contact the manufacturer to inquire about the valid FPS ranges. Have you tried any existing camera apps on this board? If you have, and they are exhibiting similar sorts of problems, that would be further indication that the issue lies in the device and/or Android build.

Comment: Unfortunately there was a bug in the support code for LEGACY camera2 devices in Android L, which was fixed in Android M, where the conversion between frame rate ranges was done incorrectly (the fix is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ec743ee ). This means that on L, you have to use the *1000 FPS values, and on M, the intended single-digit FPS values, with TARGET_FPS_RANGE.  That means you're setting the frame rate to 30,30 correctly, so that's not the underlying problem here.  Is the issue the same for low output resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

After talking with the board manufacturer, It seems that there are some issues with the implementation and they are working on fixing them.

I would like to thank @CommonsWare and @EddyTalvala for their expertise in helping me find the issue here.

-Rob

Comment: I am also using Camera2 API on OpenQ 410 and experiencing low FPS. Did you find a fix? What is the issue with the board manufacturer you were speaking of?